# HDF5 file to diagram in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, hdf5, pytables

I'm trying to generate some diagrams from an .h5 file but I don't know how to do it.
I'm using pytables, numpy and matplotlib.

The hdf5 files I use contains 2 sets of data, 2 differents curves.
My goal is to get diagrams [like this one](http://philippe.berger2.free.fr/automatique/cours/LB/logiqu2.gif).

This is what I managed to do for the moment:

```
import  tables  as tb
import  numpy   as np
import  matplotlib.pyplot   as plt

h5file = tb.openFile(args['FILE'], "a")
for group in h5file.walkGroups("/"):
     for array in h5file.walkNodes("/","Array"):
          if(isinstance(array.atom.dflt, int)):
               tab = np.array(array.read())
               x = tab[0]
               y = tab[1]
               plt.plot(x, y)
               plt.show()
```

x and y values are good but I don't know how to use them, so the result is wrong. I get a triangle instead of what I want ^^

Thank you for your help

**EDIT**

I solved my problem.

Here is the code :

```
fig = plt.figure()

tableau = np.array(array.read())
x = tableau[0]
y = tableau[1]
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)

ax1.plot(x)
ax2.plot(y)

plt.title(array.name)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you perhaps have an example of the x and y values?

Comment: tab is a table of tables, x and y are tables that contains just 0 and 1